# How to rewrite url for url with multiple query parameter?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Server: **Nginx**

Application: **PHP**

URL in question is

> /p/all_articles/user/ABC
>
> /p/all_articles/user/ABC/page/123

which is

> /index.php?p=all_articles&user=ABC
>
> /index.php?p=all_articles&user=ABC&page=123

```
ABC = this could be a-zA-Z0-9 as it's username
123 = this could be page numbers 0-9
```

Tried many combinations and options, the following got me much closer to expected result, but it is not perfect.

```
location /p/all_articles {
    rewrite ^/p/all_articles/user/(.*)?$ /index.php?p=all_articles&user=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/p/all_articles/user/(.*)/page(?:/([0-9]+))?$ /index.php?p=all_articles&user=$1&page=$2 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

the above rewrite location block results only when one of them is quoted other one would work, but not together.

---

Similarly

> /search/QUERY
>
> /search/QUERY/page/123

which is

> /index.php?search=QUERY
>
> /index.php?search=QUERY&page=123

```
QUERY = anything a-zA-Z0-9 and space
123 = this could be page numbers 0-9
```

like the one for all_articles, the closest I was able to get is

```
location /search {
    rewrite ^/search /index.php?search last;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)/page(?:/([0-9]+))?$ /index.php?search=$1&page=$2 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

But, this works to get either one of the clean URL when the other rewrite is quoted, but not together.

I appreciate if anyone give any answers to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` statements are evaluated in order so the more specific regular expression needs to be placed before a less specific regular expression.

With the two regular expressions:

```
^/search
^/search/(.*)/page(?:/([0-9]+))?$
```

The first one will match anything that also matches the second, so the second regular expression will never be evaluated.

The simple solution is to reverse the order of the `rewrite` statements in both of your `location` blocks.